# ASP.Net MVC 3 Controller Inheritence

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following inheritance hierarchy in my ASP.net MVC 3 app:

```
  public class HomeController : AuthenticatedBaseController
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}   


public class AuthenticatedBaseController : BaseController
{
    public AuthenticatedBaseController() 
    {
        if (!this.UserToken.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
        }
    }

}

public class BaseController : Controller
{

    private Token _token;
    public Token UserToken
    {
        get
        {
            _token = (Token)(Session["token"]);
            if (_token == null)
            {
                SetToken();
            }
            return _token;
        }
    }

    public void SetToken()
    {
        _token = new Token(Session.SessionID, Request.Url.Host, Request.Url.ToString());
        Session["token"] = _token;
    }
}
```

I am finding that the constructor of the `AuthenticatedBaseController` is firing twice when I make a GET request to /Home. Can someone help tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Good starting point is to use Fiddler to rule out that the browser is not actually sending out two GET requests.

Comment: You should be using `Authorize` authorization filters.

Comment: This is a very insecure way to do authentication.  It's much easier to hijack a session cookie than it is an authorization cookie.  You should be using the AuthorizeAttribute, and use FormsAuthentication class to generate authentication tickets.  Or, implement your own IIdentity based service and use that.

Comment: Another reason this is bad is that sessions are unreliable.  They can disappear at any time, such as when the worker process is restarted, or if the server gets low on memory.  You really don't want the user potentially having to login every 2 minutes because the server can't keep that many sessions around.  Authentication tickets are cookie based, and thus survive session restarts.

Comment: Unfortunately this requirement comes for the client. I do not have a say in the matter. Also the above code is a very simplified version of the actual code, but maintains the essential logic.

Comment: @klork - Really.  Your client insists that a 5 year old should be able to hack their system, steal information, and destroy data.  YOU will be the one blamed when it's hacked, and it will be.  If you don't tell them, they will never know that their requirement caused the problem.

Comment: @klork - When it comes to security, there's no such thing as "client requirement" for a consultant if the requirement is insecure.  It's your reputation that's on the line, and you will get a bad one if you willingly write insecure code.  They will (rightly, i might add) say that even if it was their requirement, it is your job as the "expert" to tell them if it's insecure, and not doing so would be a breach of your ethics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, it's firing twice because you are redirecting the user to another action, which causes another request, which causes another controller instance to be created.

Comment: The controller to which the redirect points does not inherit the AuthenticatedBaseController.

Comment: @klork - upon further analysis, your code can't even work.  RedirectToAction is not a command.  You have to RETURN a redirect to action from an action method.  You can't just call it, it will do nothing.

Comment: yep, that was the issue. Thanks